# In a PyQt application when I try to show dialog windows from a long-running singleShot task they don't get rendred

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a command-line application that runs a long task. I am currently trying to add a user interface to it and I am using Qt. The application has to occasionally notify the user via two dialog windows, and no matter what I try I cannot make it work.

So what I do is the following: I first construct a `QApplication`, then I create a single-shot `QTimer` that executes then long-running task and then I launch `exec()` method of the application. Inside a long-running task then I try to call `show()` and `hide()` methods of the dialog windows, but the windows are not properly rendered and are simply shown in black (at least in Ubuntu 18.04).

If I call `exec()` method of the dialog window from a long-running task the dialog is rendered properly but this, of course, blocks the task until the window is closed.

Is there a way to make it work without blocking the long-running task?

See the code below for a minimal non-working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import sys
import time

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    """Dialog window with just a text label."""

    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        self.text = text
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.text)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)


class Application(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    """An example QApplication launching the worker function."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.root = Dialog("Root window")
        self.dialog_a = Dialog("Dialog A")
        self.dialog_b = Dialog("Dialog B")

    def show_a(self):
        self.dialog_b.hide()
        self.dialog_a.show()

    def show_b(self):
        self.dialog_a.hide()
        self.dialog_b.show()

    def exec(self):
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: worker(self))
        super().exec()


def worker(app):
    """
    This is the main worker function that should occasionaly ask
    Application to show different dialog windows.  Unfortunately the
    windows do not get rendered until the worker function is done.
    """

    app.show_a()
    for _ in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(".")

    app.show_b()
    for _ in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(".")


app = Application([])
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your worker function blocks the whole event loop, that's why you dont see any dialog.
To execute a long running function, it is best to move it into a new thread. In QT, threads are not allowed to access widgets, so you need to work with signals between the threads to make the main thread showing the dialog, you want to.

You will see Dialog A for 5 seconds while the threads writes to stdout, after Dialog B is shown:

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QThread, QObject, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, QTimer


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    """Dialog window with just a text label."""

    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        self.text = text
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.text)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)


class Application(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    """An example QApplication launching the worker function."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._threads = []

        self.root = Dialog("Root window")
        self.dialog_a = Dialog("Dialog A")
        self.dialog_b = Dialog("Dialog B")

        self.dialog_a.hide()
        self.dialog_b.hide()

        worker = Worker()
        wThread = QThread()
        wThread.setObjectName('worker')
        self._threads.append((wThread, worker))  # you need to keep track of the threads and instances.
        worker.moveToThread(wThread)
        worker.showDialog.connect(self._switchDialog)  # connect the signal from the thread to a function to show/hide the dialogs.
        wThread.started.connect(worker.start)
        wThread.start()

    def _switchDialog(self, dialogId):
        if dialogId == 'a':
            self.show_a()
        else:
            self.show_b()

    def show_a(self):
        self.dialog_b.hide()
        self.dialog_a.show()

    def show_b(self):
        self.dialog_a.hide()
        self.dialog_b.show()



class Worker(QObject):
    showDialog = pyqtSignal(str)

    """
    This is the main worker function that should occasionaly ask
    Application to show different dialog windows.  Unfortunately the
    windows do not get rendered until the worker function is done.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('setup worker')

    @pyqtSlot()
    def start(self):
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.run)
        self.timer.start()

    def run(self):
        for dialog in ('a', 'b'):
            print ("showing dialog: %s" % dialog)
            self.showDialog.emit(dialog)
            for _ in range(10):
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print(".")

app = Application([])
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note: This is how it works in general, i tried to keep most of your code. Please review some PyQt threading tutorials for more information.

Comment: Thanks! Can't run the code at the moment, but your explanation makes total sense. I falsely assumed that QTimer starts a separate thread in background. If it's running in the same thread as the rest of the application that explains all the problems I saw with my original code.

Answer (score 1):

You are needing the [QApplication.processEvents()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.root = Dialog("Root window")
    self.dialog_a = Dialog("Dialog A", parent=self.root)
    self.dialog_b = Dialog("Dialog B", parent=self.root)

def show_a(self):
    self.dialog_b.hide()
    self.dialog_a.show()
    self.processEvents()

def show_b(self):
    self.dialog_a.hide()
    self.dialog_b.show()
    self.processEvents()
```

Comment: Strange, that worked for me. I added a few lines to this code, could you try that? Declaring the root dialog object as parent of the other dialogs could help...